# Running Eclipse from usb

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, usb

I have put the necessary files on my USB pen drive, the Java Development Kit and the Eclipse files. I have created a .bat file which reads

```
@echo off

set Path=\32 Bit\jdk32\bin;%Path%

cd "32 Bit\Eclipse"
start eclipse.exe

exit
```

However when I run the batch, Eclipse launches and brings the error

[image: Eclipse Error]

As far as I can tell this is trying to use my old path variable for the JNI Shared Library. Could someone help me with this problem please.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with your "set Path" if that is happening.

Comment: Do you have a '-vm' entry in your 'eclipse.ini' file?

Comment: @greg-449 I have -vmargs in the .ini file if that effects it?

Comment: @MichaelS It should work without quotes, just like Set Path=java\jdk6\bin;%Path% for example

Comment: @user3272243 would the \ before 32 Bit effect it?

Comment: @Dan Yeah, perhaps, depending of your path that could be it.

Comment: @user3272243 Unfortunately it did not effect it

Comment: @Dan If its not that try giving a look to this tutorial, in case its not the one you have tried http://cis.csuohio.edu/~sschung/CIS260/Running-Java-Eclipse-From-USB-Flash-Drive.pdf Maybe you are missing a previous step.

Comment: '-vmargs' is OK, sometimes people put an explicit path in the eclipse.ini using '-vm'.

Comment: @user3272243 I believe the problem is the fact that I am not setting the directory as the usb. Because when I remove `@echo off` it doesn't have `N:\Code\Java\Eclipse Mars\32 Bit\jdk32\bin` it only has `32 Bit\jdk32\bin`. How would one make it auto detect the correct directory?

Comment: i.e in that tutorial the person types `c> E:` how would you auto detect the drive volume and file location so it is not needed to type `N:\Code\Java\Eclipse Mars` previously

Comment: @Dan You could try creating an environment variable, but I'm not sure if that's what you want since you are creating a portable usb installation. If you are going to use it in several computers you'll need to create that environment variable in every single computer you use (which in my opinion would be a pain and it will make the usb "less portable").

Comment: @user3272243 Found a fix for this

Comment: @Dan Sorry I couldn't help you much. lol

Comment: @user3272243 No worries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is a really simple solution to this.

**Amended .bat file**

```
@echo off

set Path=%~dp032 Bit\jdk32\bin;%Path%

cd "32 Bit\Eclipse"
start eclipse.exe

exit
```

**Explanation**

This works by getting the path of an executing batch file using the command `%~dp0`.

Where

- d is the drive (in this case `N:\`)
- p is the path (`Code\Java\Eclipse Mars\`)
- 0 is the name of the executing batch file

This path `N:\Code\Java\Eclipse Mars\32 Bit\jdk32\bin` which sets the Java version correctly and removes the error I had above

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the batch script you can just change the -vm config directive and it will build the virtual machine from the exe for java you give it. 
ex. -vm C:\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe. https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Linux_Example